# How to run Python's subprocess and leave it in background

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I have seen A LOT of posts regarding my topic, but actually I didn't find a solution for my problem.
I'm trying to run a subprocess in a background, without wait for subprocess execution. The called subprocess is a shell script, which does a lot of different things.
This is a small piece of my code:

```
print "Execute command:", full_command
subprocess.Popen(full_command, stdin=None, stdout=None, stderr=None, close_fds=True).communicate()
print "After subprocess"
```

And my problem is that Python waits until subprocess.Popen finishes it's job. I read, that stdin(-out, -err)=None should solve this problem, but it's not. Also close_fds=True, doesn't help here.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From the [`Popen.communicate` documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) (emphasis mine):

> Interact with process: Send data to stdin. Read data from stdout and
>   stderr, until end-of-file is reached. **Wait for process to terminate.**
>   The optional input argument should be a string to be sent to the child
>   process, or None, if no data should be sent to the child.

If you don't want to wait for the process to terminate, then simply don't call `communicate`:

```
subprocess.Popen(full_command, close_fds=True)
```

Comment: @mchfrnc I have to concede the name of the method doesn't make that side effect very clear! ; )

Answer (score 2):

Might be another way of doing it, with the optional capability to inspect the subprocess output for a while, from github.com/hologram-io/hologram-python pppd.py file:

```
    self.proc = Popen(self._commands, stdout=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)

    # set stdout to non-blocking
    fd = self.proc.stdout.fileno()
    fl = fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_GETFL)
    fcntl.fcntl(fd, fcntl.F_SETFL, fl | os.O_NONBLOCK)
```