# Python: Keep processes started by subprocess.Popen alive after exiting

Tags: python, subprocess

I am making a virtual assistant that can start several programs using `subprocess.Popen("path/to/app.exe")`. But when I exit the python program, all of processes are killed. I want the processes (the applications started with Popen) to be independent and remain alive after main process is killed.

I have tried adding `start_new_session=True` as argument in `subprocess.Popen()` as some posts have suggested, but it's still not working.

I don't think showing the code is necessary, but still, here you go.

```py
app_path = r'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9001\discord.exe'
subprocess.Popen(app_path)  # also tried adding start_new_session=True as argument
```

Comment: `app_path = r'C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9001\discord.exe'

subprocess.Popen(['start', app_path])`

Does this work? (can't easily test; not on windows at the moment).

Comment: Can't reproduce/test with discord on my computer, but maybe a creation flag can help you, like DETACHED_PROCESS or CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#windows-constants

Comment: @jrbergen I tried your solution, but it shows `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified`, even though I am 100% sure the file exists.

Comment: @Talon Am I supposed to use it like `import subprocess    subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS = True`? If so, it still doesn't work; But I might be using it wrong.

Comment: @KirkKD you pass flags to Popen with `subprocess.Popen(app_path, creationflags=subprocess.DETACHED_PROCESS)`. If you want multiple flags, you join them together with the `|` logic-or operator.

Comment: @Talon Thank you, but the child processes still get kill with the python program.

Comment: @Kirk KD What happens if you try it with quotes (not sure if it would matter as there are no spaces in the pathname though). Like this:
app_path = r'"C:\Users\myusername\AppData\Local\Discord\app-1.0.9001\discord.exe"'  subprocess.Popen(['start', app_path])

Comment: @jrbergen I did wrap the path in quotes when testing and I tried paths both with and without spaces in them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're on Windows, you can call the [`start`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/start) command, which exists for this very purpose: to run another program independently of the one that starts it.

The `start` command is provided by the command-line interpreter [`cmd.exe`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cmd.exe). It is not an executable: there is no `start.exe`. It is a "shell command" (in Linux terminology), which is why [`shell=True`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments) must be passed when creating the subprocess.

You won't be able to communicate with the subprocess started in this way, that is, not via the pipe mechanism provided by the [`subprocess`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html) module. So instead of [`Popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen), you may just use the convenience function [`run`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.run):

```py
from subprocess import run
app = 'notepad'
run(['start', app], shell=True)
```

The example starts the Notepad editor (instead of Discord in the question) in order to make it easier to reproduce.

In cases where the full path to the `app` contains spaces, we can either call `start` like so

```py
app = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe'
run(f'start "" "{app}"', shell=True)
```

using the Edge browser in this example, or pass the directory separately:

```py
folder = r'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application'
app = 'msedge.exe'
run(['start', '/d', folder, app], shell=True)
```

This is needed because `start` treats a single argument as the window title if that argument is in quotes. And only if not does it treat it as the command. See ["Can I use the `start` command with spaces in the path?"](https://superuser.com/q/239565) (on SuperUser) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34718600/4355695

```
subprocess.Popen(full_command, shell=True, close_fds=True)
```

(In my linux system I have to put shell=True if I'm passing a full command as string instead of a split-up array of arguments. In windows it may differ, idk)