# Python subprocess kills child process automatically, different from other cases in the internet

Tags: python, multiprocessing, subprocess

Lots of cases in the internet told me that, subprocess.Popen() will start the childprocess and not wait it completed.
But in my cases, the Popen() will not start the childprocess unless it execute longer than the childprocess.

the childprocess "test.py" will not write words in the test.txt, unless the "testsub.py" execute the p.wait().

test.py

```
import time

with open(r"test.txt", "a") as myfile:
    myfile.write("TXT start!\n")
    time.sleep(10)
    myfile.write("TXT End\n")
```

testsub.py

```
import subprocess

p = subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=False)
# p.wait()
print("father process finished!")
```

Comment: Make sure you are looking at the file only after flushing or closing it.

Comment: If you delete test.txt before the test, will an empty text.txt appear?

Comment: While I closed this with one duplicate, _if you're on Windows_ there may be a second relevant one at [Keep processes started by `subprocess.Popen` alive after exiting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67578348/python-keep-processes-started-by-subprocess-popen-alive-after-exiting); the question doesn't specify an operating system so we can't presently tell.

Comment: The parent process exit kills the child process before it has flushed data to the disk. Whether its had time to even create the file is up for grabs.

Comment: As a side note, `p = subprocess.Popen("python test.py", shell=False)` does not work on linux. It does work on windows because even supposedly non-shell execution is built into a single command string.